# extend EntityType, set choices to selected Entity only

Tags: forms, symfony, jquery-select2

I've extended Symfony's `EntityType` as `UserChooserType` for use with my `User` entity and Select2. The choice list for the `UserChooserType` comes from an ldap query (via an ajax call), not a Doctrine query. So the field starts out blank.

The User entity is related to many different entities across my application. But if I want the UserChooserType to load with <del>a current</del> the selected User I have to add a listener to every form that uses it. e.g.:

```
class SiteType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $siteAdminOpts = array('label' => 'entity.site.admin', 'required'=>false);
       //opts for the UserChooserType

        $builder
            ->add('siteName', FT\TextType::class, array('label' => 'entity.site.name'))
            ->add('siteAdmin', UserChooserType::class, $siteAdminOpts )

           //must be added to every form type that uses UserChooserType with mod for the datatype that $event->getData() returns
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event){
                $site = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm(); //SiteType

                if($user = $site->getSiteAdmin()) $siteAdminOpts['choices'] = array($user);
                $form->add('siteAdmin', UserChooserType::class, $siteAdminOpts);
            });
    }
//etc.
```

---

### tldr;

I'd like to either:

- set `UserChooserType`'s `choices` option to the selected user in `UserChooserType::configureOptions()`, or
- move `->addEventListener(...)` into `UserChooserType::buildForm()`.

Any idea how it might be done?

---

Here is the UserChooserType:

```
class UserChooserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var UserManager
     */
    protected $um;

    /**
     * UserChooserType constructor.
     * @param UserManager $um
     */
    public function __construct(UserManager $um){
        $this->um = $um; //used to find and decorate User entities. It is not a Doctrine entity manager, but it uses one.
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();

            if (!$data) return;

            $user = $this->um->getUserByUserName($data);
            if(!$user->getId()) $this->um->saveUser($user); //create User in db, if it's not there yet.
        });

        $builder->resetViewTransformers(); //so new choices aren't discarded
        
        $builder->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
          function ($user) { //internal storage format to display format
            return ($user instanceof User) ? $user->getUserName() : '';
          },
          function ($username) { //display format to storage format
              return ($username) ? $this->um->getUserByUserName($username) : null;
          }
        ));
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'class' => 'ACRDUserBundle:User',
            'label' => 'ldap.user.name',
            'choice_label' => function($user, $key, $index){
                $this->um->decorateUser($user);
                $label = $user->getDetail('displayName');
                return $label ? $label : $user->getUserName();
            },
            'choice_value' => 'userName',
            'choices' => [],
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'userchooser',
                'placeholder' => 'form.placeholder.userchooser'
            )

        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'my_userchooser';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getParent() {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick q: You're looking to constrain the choices to *only* the logged in user? Or have them be the default choice?

Comment: @CameronHurd: I want to constrain choices to only the user (if there is one) already attached to an entity. The logged in user will likely be someone else entirely. e.g. `$site1:siteAdmin = $user1`. so `UserChooserType` choices opt should contain `$user1` only, and it should be marked as "selected". But `$office2:coordinator = null`, so its `UserChooserType` choices should be empty. The other choices are populated via Ajax when someone types a search string.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me out:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-choices

Here is how I used it (again with select 2):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    /** @var ProductCollection $productCollection */
    $productCollection = $builder->getData();

    $builder
        ->add('products', EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => Product::class,
                'required' => FALSE,
                'expanded' => FALSE,
                'multiple' => TRUE,
                'choices' => $productCollection->getProducts(), // We only preload the selected products. The rest come from api.
                'attr' => [
                    'data-toggle' => 'select',
                    'data-options' => json_encode([
                        'ajax' => [
                            'url' => '/admin/product/autocomplete',
                            'dataType' => 'json'
                        ]
                    ])
                ],
                'choice_label' => function (Product $product) {
                    return $product->getName();
                },
                'choice_attr' => function (Product $product) {
                    return [
                        'data-avatarsrc' => $product->getImage()->getUrl(),
                        'data-caption' => $product->getSkus()->first()->getSku(),
                    ];
                },
            ]
        )
    ;
}
```

And here is my JS for the init of the select2 (copy/paste):

```
function() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="select"]');

    function templateResult(element) {
      let avatarsrc, caption;

      if (element.id && element.avatarsrc) {
        avatarsrc = element.avatarsrc
        caption = element.caption ? ' ' + element.caption : ''
      }
      else if (element.element) {
        avatarsrc = element.element.dataset.avatarsrc ? element.element.dataset.avatarsrc : ''
        caption = element.element.dataset.caption ? ' ' + element.element.dataset.caption : ''
      }

      if (!avatarsrc) {
        return element.text + caption
      }

      let wrapper = document.createElement("div");
      return wrapper.innerHTML = '<span class="avatar avatar-xs mr-3 my-2"><img class="avatar-img rounded-circle" src="' + avatarsrc + '" alt="' + element.text + '"></span><span>' + element.text + '</span><span class="badge badge-soft-success ml-2">' + caption + '</span>', wrapper
    }
    
    jQuery().select2 && elements && [].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
      var select, additionalOptions, select2options;

      additionalOptions = (select = element).dataset.options ? JSON.parse(select.dataset.options) : {};

      select2options = {
        containerCssClass: select.getAttribute("class"),
        dropdownCssClass: "dropdown-menu show",
        dropdownParent: select.closest(".modal") ? select.closest(".modal") : document.body,
        templateResult: templateResult,
        templateSelection: templateResult
      }

      $(select).select2({...select2options, ...additionalOptions})
    })
  }(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks first:

- The field name `UserChooserType` is a bit elaborated. `UserType` is shorter and just as clear, and fits the Symfony naming conventions better
- I wouldn't extend `UserChooserType` from `EntityType`. Doc says `EntityType` is specifically dedicated to entities coming from Doctrine. It adds magic so that the field is easily configured around Doctrine: transformers, automatic fetching of choices from the DB, etc. If your users are fully defined in the LDAP, I would instead recommend extending `ChoiceType` and populate your choices from the LDAP directly.

Coming back to your problem, what you want here is to leverage the almighty power of dependency injection, by declaring your [field type as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service). After having done that, instead of:

```
$builder->add('siteAdmin', UserChooserType::class, $siteAdminOpts)
```

You will do (assuming you chose the form name `user_chooser_type`):

```
$builder->add('siteAdmin', 'user_chooser_type', $siteAdminOpts)
```

You need to inject the `security.token_storage` service into your field type. This is the service that holds the current user's information, you can access it like this:

`$user = $securityTokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();`

With this the population of the default value can happen at the field type level instead of its parent.

Using this, you could also add the LDAP choices at field type level too, by injecting a service able to communicate with the LDAP.

It should finally noted that all default symfony field types are also declared as services.

**EDIT:**

Previous answer is beside the point.

In Symfony, I'm not aware of any possible simple way to modify the choice list of a choice/entity field after it has been created. I don't think there is, and actually I might have done the same as you to tackle the issue you're describing.

My opinion is that you're already doing what needs to be done in this case.

If you're really motivated though, I think it might just be possible to move the event listener in the form type like this:

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
    if ($form->hasParent()) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $method = 'get' . ucfirst($form['action_name']);
        if($user = $data->$method()) $siteAdminOpts['choices'] = array($user);
        $form->getParent()->add($options['form_name'], UserChooserType::class, $siteAdminOpts);
    }
});
```

Something like that. Not sure how that would work though.

I'm still interested in seeing if anyone comes up with a clean solution.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. But I don't need the security token. The user that is attached to some entity will likely not be the current user.  2nd, my form class is a service. Symfony3 has deprecated short-naming. 3rd, the UserManager communicates with Ldap, and is a service. 4th, the User object is a Doctrine entity *and* it's related to an ldap object. It's  similar to  a mixed ORM and ODM system except with ldap instead of ODM. And last, your suggestions don't address the core issue that the query that populates `choices` needs to know what the selected value is before it does the query.

Comment: Ok thanks for underlining the depreciation, I wasn't up-to-date on this apparently. Also... as I remember it, `EntityType` will fail at validation if you select a choice that is not in the choices list. In the current state of things, do the validation step work? Finally, have you tried to leave `choices` with its default value instead of forcing an empty array?

Comment: `choicetype` and `entitytype` both fail when a submitted choice isn't in the list. `$builder->resetViewTransformers();` gets around that problem. If I leave `choices` at default, it populates the list with every User in the db. I currently have ~100 Users in the db and more to come. Since every instantiation of a User entity also requires an ldap query, I don't want to load Users until they're actually required.